# IntelliJ debug config for remote Jetty server

Tags: intellij-idea, jetty, vagrant, jetty-9, intellij-14

I'm trying to setup a debug configuration in IntelliJ to remotely connect to a running Jetty server.

Setup is:

- Host machine where IntelliJ is running is Mac OS X
- Jetty is running inside a Vagrant managed guest VM on my Mac
- Per [IntelliJ's instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/run-debug-configuration-jetty.html) I've also installed Jetty locally on the host Mac
- There is a shared folder between host/guest where all the Java code lives, let's call it /Development/myproject
- The guest VM is visible to my Mac host via the IP address 10.10.10.10
- I have configured jetty to start in debug mode by passing in these args on the java command line:

  -Xdebug -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=57896,suspend=n,server=y
- Note that the war file in the guest VM gets deployed to a directory that is not shared with the host (at least the dir is not shared yet...but if I needed I could figure out a way to do it)

All I want to do is attach to an already running Jetty instance so that I can set breakpoints and step through the code. (Extra credit would be getting IntelliJ to actually deploy and to the remote server and hot-swap when classes are changed...but baby steps!)

***So my question is, given all this information what are all the correct values to fill in, in the IntelliJ dialog box below?***

What should the JMX port be set to? The same port I set above in -agentlib on the command-line? 57896?

What about the other fields?

Thanks much in advance!

[image: IntelliJ Debug Configuration Dialog]